# Magento 2 2.3 Full Page Cart issue

Tags: caching, magento2, cart, shopping-cart

Is currently working on a new M2 2.3 site to replace my M1.
Almost done but I have found an issue with the cart and full page cache.

When full page cache is enable and I add a product to cart its all good. But when I move to another category and add another product the cart gets empty and start all over again.

If I disable the full page cache the cart works fine.

Anyone have an idea of what i might be?

The site is still in devolopment.

Comment: Set Cookie Path ->  Cookie Domain -> your domain.com

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the `Magento_Persistent` module. There is a native bug with FPC when you disable this module. The issue has been reported in the link below:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21614